# What is the type of event handler attached to the window object in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, events, next.js

I'm working on a Next.js app, and I found out that the type I assigned to the event throws me an error.

Here is my code so far:

```
const keyboard = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!showKeyboard) return; // If the keyboard is not shown then we don't need a listener to hide it, so we stop here.

    // Hide the keyboard if a click was triggered outside the keyboard.
    function hideKeyboard(event: Event) {
        if (
            keyboard.current &&
            event != null &&
            !keyboard.current.contains(event?.target)
        ) {
            setShowKeyboard(false);
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener('click', hideKeyboard);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('click', hideKeyboard); // Remove the listener.
}, [showKeyboard]);
```

The app runs and works as expected, however an error is thrown by TypeScript:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'EventTarget | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node | null'.<br/>Type 'EventTarget' is missing the following properties from type 'Node': baseURI, childNodes, firstChild, isConnected, and 43 more.
```

I have also tried  `React.MouseEvent<Window>` and `React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>`. However, the same error is thrown plus the next one:

```
No overload matches this call.   
Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "click", listener: (this: Window, ev: MouseEvent) => any, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
Argument of type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Window, ev: MouseEvent) => any'.       
    Types of parameters 'event' and 'ev' are incompatible.         
    Type 'MouseEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>': nativeEvent, isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped, persist   Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.     
Argument of type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.       
Type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.         Types of parameters 'event' and 'evt' are incompatible.           Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>': altKey, button, buttons, clientX, and 18 more.
```

My code works as expected in all the 3 types I have tried. The only way for me to hide the TS errors is using `any`, but that is not the best practice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show how you declared `keyboard` and use it?

Comment: Done. It's a div that contains buttons to represent a keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hover over `addEventListener`, TypeScript tells you that the correct definition for a click handler for the `window` object would be `(this: Window, ev: MouseEvent) => any`.

Beyond that, for `hideKeyboard`, you would need an `event.target instanceof Node` check, as `contains()` expect a `Node` element and `event.target` is of type [EventTarget](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5138) | `null`.

```
function hideKeyboard(this: Window, event: MouseEvent):any {
  if (!showKeyboard) return; 
  if (
    keyboard.current &&
    event.target instanceof Node &&
    !keyboard.current.contains(event.target)
  ) {
    setShowKeyboard(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works and makes sense. But I prefered to use void as the return type of my function since I'm not returning anything. Di you have any particular reason to set it to any?

Comment: Hi @Herii, glad I could help! I used `any` because it's the expected type. If you hover over `addEventListener` you will see `listener: (this: Window, ev: MouseEvent) => any`.